# Loading dynamically generated content and URL after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Google Instant style search script written in jQuery. When a user searches, a URL is created which is something like #search/**QUERY**/3/. However, when you either reload the page, click a result which goes to a different page or return back from a previous page the search results are no longer there. Why could this be?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        var query=encodeURIComponent(search);
        var page=1;
        var yt_url='search.php?q='+query+'&category=web&d='+page+'';
        window.location.hash='search/'+query+'/'+page+'/';
        document.title=$(this).val()+" - My Search Script";
        if(search==''){
            window.location.hash='';
            document.title='My Search Script';
        }
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:yt_url,
            dataType:"html",
            success:function(response){
                if(response !=""){
                $("#result").html(response);
                } else {
                $("#result").html("Your search did not return any results");
                }
            }
        });
    });
if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#search/')==0){
    query=window.location.hash.replace('#search/', '').replace('/1/', '');
    $('#search').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
}
});
```

I think it could be something to do with these lines of code:

```
if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#search/')==0){
    query=window.location.hash.replace('#search/', '').replace('/1/', '');
    $('#search').val(decodeURIComponent(query)).keyup();
}
```

Comment: I created a page with your javascript code the textbox and a result div, and it works as expected on Firefox and Chrome. Maybe something else is overwriting your content, or you are binding/removing events from the textbox.

Comment: But have you tried removing everything except what you pasted in here? Making it as simple as possible.

Comment: This works? http://kisurfer.com/test.html

Comment: That works fine for me. I type 'abcdef', click on the google link, when I click back, It refreshes 'abcdef', if I type '1234' and refresh, it loads up with '1234'. Chrome 11.0

Comment: If I copy the url http://kisurfer.com/test.html#search/abcde/1/ and paste it in any browser it loads up with the results.
What do you mean by paging? pagination?

Comment: I posted a solution, that should prolly help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a function for the search so you can specify the page number.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var search = function (query, page) {
    page = page ? page : 1;
    query = encodeURIComponent(query),
    var yt_url = 'search.php?q=' + query + '&category=web&d=' + page + '';
    if (query == '') {
        window.location.hash = '';
        document.title = 'My Search Script';
    } else {
      window.location.hash = 'search/' + query + '/' + page + '/';
      document.title = $(this).val() + " - My Search Script";
    }
    $.ajax({ ... });
  };

  $("#search").keyup(function(){ search(this.value); });

  if (window.location.hash.indexOf('#search/') == 0) {
    var query = window.location.hash.replace('#search/', ''),
      page = query.replace(/.+?\/(\d+)\//, '$1');
    query = query.replace(/\/\d+\//, '');
    search(decodeURIComponent(query), page);
  }
});
```